# Print one custom row amongst mysql_fetch_array rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My problem is this: I'm listing stuff from my database with `mysql_fetch_array`. I want to print custom row after 2nd loop iteration and before 3rd. So basically 3rd printed row is not coming from database. I have tried to create a running number for each iteration and then using if-function but this replaces 3rd row and it does not appear as 4th.

My code:

```
<?
$iteration = '0';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($my_data))
{

    $iteration = $iteration + 1;

    if ($iteration =='3')
    {
        echo "My special row";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $row['name'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just remove `else`.

Comment: *"My problem is ... mysql_fetch_array*" would also be accurate since the `mysql_` extension is obsolete.

Comment: Also, `$iteration` should be a number, not a string. Remove the quotes around `0` and `3`

Comment: Thanks!!! Removing else did the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `else` from your code to print 3rd row main contents also after your custom row as following:-

```
<?php

$iteration = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($my_data)){
     $iteration = $iteration + 1;
     if ($iteration ==3){
          echo "My special row";
     }
     echo $row['name'];
}

?>
```